# difference between webservices and API'S?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api

What is the difference between webservices and API'S accesed through http ..
ONTO MY UNDERSTANDING BOTH ARE used for calling external websites or app's services..
plz tell me with some examples on it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are virtually synonymous in this case. A webservice is a http exposed API. This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservice) has a good discussion.